# Android Studio Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes

Tags: android, android-studio, dex

Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes

I got this error after merging my files. I spend around one day to resolve this. Searched other stackoverflow answers, nothing worked.

Comment: I put this up to help others to save some time.

Answer (score 4):

after spending about a day, i found the answer.
There was package capitalization mismatch.
my package was com.example.utils, but in some android file it was imported as com.example.Utils

I hope this will help others to save a day or two.
Gradle should be more smart to point right problem than giving some general  Exception parsing classes